# Print my submission entry

Tags: quine

Your program should print the following:

````
**Language, XXX bytes**

```
CODE
```
````

or its equivalent. `XXX` should be substituted by the actual number of bytes your program takes, and `CODE` should be substituted by the source code of your program. `Language` should be substituted by the actual language your program is in.

Your program will have all strings exactly equal to their language name substituted to the empty string before its byte count is counted. For instance:

```python
print("PytPythonPythonhon")
```

and

```python
print("PPPPPPythonythonythonythonythonython")
```

have the same byte count.

Comment: Why `**` and not `#`?

Comment: For bold? IHATE15CHAR

Comment: "Your program will have all strings exactly equal to their language name substituted to the empty string before its byte count is counted." - I don't understand what this means?

Comment: whoops IHATE15CHAR